# Multiple Line of Text Columns, I am not able to do any formatting while using it with Publishing Layout Pages

Tags: publishing-site, ribbon

I'm wondering if Multiple Line of Text Columns works with Publishing Layouts for Publishing Site or not? The problem is while adding them to a publishing layout page (either column set to be RichText or EnhancedRichText) the format toolbar is not coming for these fields (not shown in Ribbon toolbar). But while trying to edit page properties from Pages List, columns are coming with their format toolbar.

So, is Multiple Line of Text Column work with publishing site or not? If so, how to do this?

**[Edit]**
If I modified the column content format and saved the page (editing page properties from Pages List) the column content is rendered properly with the formats I've applied. But while editing the page from Ribbon toolbar the content comes like this

```
<strong>Decision Trees <font color="#ff6600">Decision </font>Trees </strong><em>Decision Trees</em>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using this column, modify the element as follows:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Title" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on this answer to help solve the question?